# Melhoria do campo de pesquisa

Tags: novo-recurso

há umas semanas fiz esta pergunta [Armazenar valores representantes do 'sexo' de um usuário em bancos de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57429/armazenar-valores-representantes-do-sexo-de-um-usu%C3%A1rio-em-bancos-de-dados), mas recentemente necessitei voltar a esta pergunta então digitei erroneamente a palavra `sex` no campo de pesquisa acreditando que encontraria minha pergunta rapidamente porem só encontrei perguntas que casavam com a minha string de busca `sex`. logo gostaria de deixar uma sugestão para que a busca possa buscar por variações da `string de busca` como `LIKE %busca%` (solução simplória) e possa ter uma relevância de resultados sendo em primeiro lugar fique as consultas que casaram totalmente com a string de busca e subsequentemente as que casaram com as variações da string de busca.

Comment: Relacionado: [Quem procura, (agora) acha](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2382/3117)